# How do you install the Protobuf Compiler (Protocol Buffers / protoc) on Mac M1 ARM?

Tags: c++, macos, arm, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Here is the link to the Protocol Buffers / Protobuf Github
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

Should I follow the C++ installation instructions?
There is no pre-built binary for Mac M1 ARM architecture.

> "Protocol Compiler Installation
> The protocol compiler is written in C++. If you are using C++, please follow the C++ Installation Instructions to install protoc along with the C++ runtime. 
> For non-C++ users, the simplest way to install the protocol compiler is to download a pre-built binary from our release page:

> https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

> In the downloads section of each release, you can find pre-built binaries in zip packages: protoc-$VERSION-$PLATFORM.zip. It contains the protoc binary as well as a set of standard .proto files distributed along with protobuf."

Comment: At the very beginning of the release page you can read [General > Support M1 (#8557)](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/8557).

Comment: Thank you. They estimate about 4 months before a binary is available for Mac M1 ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 2nd, the estimate delivery time for the Mac M1 ARM binary is 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

For protobuf to work on Mac with the M1 chip first you will need to enable Rosseta with the following command on the terminal

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

This will allow you to run your Mac on Intel compatibility mode and then from there you can install the latest protobuf for your respective programming language.